# Python - One line for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I turn it into an easy to read,
normal nested for loops?

```
with open('csv_list.csv') as f:
    csv_list = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()}
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

Comment: What's the point of the dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('csv_list.csv') as f:
    csv_list = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True):
        row_dict = {}
        for k,v in row.items():
            row_dict[k] = v
        csv_list.append(row_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of your input an desired output?

Using a simple testfile

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

I can

```
with open('csv_list.csv') as f:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  csv_list = list(reader)
```